# Maximum value row-by-row R data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame in R, which looks something like:

```
df<-data.frame(c(1:10))
colnames(df)<-'Val'
df['Max']<-max(df$Val,5)
```

Desired output would be:

```
row, Val, Max
1  ,   1,  5
2  ,   2,  5
3  ,   3,  5
4  ,   4,  5
.....
6   ,   6, 6
```

etc etc

This is currently just giving me `10` in each row of `Max`. Help appreciated, thanks

Comment: In your dataset, there is only a single column.

Comment: Yes, I'm comparing it against a constant `5`.

Comment: `c(…)` is redundant in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `pmax`

```
df$Max <- pmax(df[,1], 5)
df
#   Val Max
#1    1   5
#2    2   5
#3    3   5
#4    4   5
#5    5   5
#6    6   6
#7    7   7
#8    8   8
#9    9   9
#10  10  10
```